# Listening for a "image upload" event

Tags: images, file-upload, plugin-events

I want to be able to programatically keep track of new images that have been added, so that I can periodically run a script that does something with the new images. My idea is to have a plugin that can listen for the event of someone adding a new image, and append its file path to a list.

Does such an event exist? Does it depend on how the image gets added? (For example they might upload the image through the media manager or through the J2Store product interface.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does such an event exist?

Core `com_media` component uses the same events as other core components: `onContentBeforeSave`, `onContentAfterSave`, `onContentBeforeDelete` and `onContentAfterDelete`. You'll need to check that context is `com.media.file`, e.g.:

```
public function onContentAfterSave($context, $item, $isNew)
{
    if ($context !== 'com_media.file')
    {
        return;
    }

    // Add your code here.
}
```

> Does it depend on how the image gets added?

Yes, other extensions may trigger different events.